# Como convertir el delimitador de un archivo csv

Tags: c#, csv

Tengo un archivo .csv lo cual cada columna y su contenido esta separado por commas.

Lo que busco hacer es poder cambiar cada separador de comas con un Pipping (|) y hacer esto en C#.

He buscado en Google pero no encuentro nada concreto que pueda ayudarme.

Muchas gracias

Comment: `string Arch = File.ReadAllText("MiCsv"); File.WriteAllText("MiNuevaRuta",  Arch.Replace(",", "|"));` ¿Algo así?

Comment: @NaCl, si esto es lo que ando buscando. Lo voy a verificar bien pero ya hice la prueba y lo cambia bien. Muchas gracias. Puedes ponerlo como respuesta para poder poder poner como respuesta buena?
Gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Algo así debería funcionar *(Insertar dentro de una función)*:

```
try 
{
    Contenido = File.ReadAllText("Ruta/De/Mi/Csv");
    File.WriteAllText("Mi/Nueva/Ruta/Del/Csv", Contenido.Replace(",", "|")
}
catch
{
     Console.WriteLine("Ha habido un error de E/S"); // Comentar si no es una aplicación de consola.
     MessageBox.Show("Ha habido un error de E/S"); // Comentar si es un Windows Forms o algo por el estilo.
}
```

El `try/catch` lo he puesto para manejo de errores, puede que intentes abrir un archivo inexistente y lanzarte una que otra `Exception`.

Recuerda hacer `using System.IO;` para poder utilizar la clase `File`.

### Método anti-comillas, Versión 2

#### Correcciones:

- El sólo poder reemplazar comas como separadores.
- No guardar el archivo automaticamente al terminar su trabajo.

En caso de error de lectura retorna `null` y en caso de error de escritura retorna el `string` modificado para evitar perder datos procesados.

---

Este otro método se encarga de reemplazar los valores de una... ¿*Mejor forma*?

Considerando que el contenido de tu csv tenga comas dentro de valores con comillas, con la solución anterior tambien se reemplazarian, por ello es necesario saber la posición exacta de las comillas para ignorarlas:

```
public string ReemplazarComasCSV(string direccion, char delim, char newdelim) {
    string Contenido = "";
    string Salida    = "";
    char   Comilla   = '\0';

    try {
        Contenido = File.ReadAllText(direccion);
    }
    catch { return null; }

    for (int i = 0; i < Contenido.Length; i++) {
        if (Contenido[i] == delim)
            Salida += newdelim;
        else if (Contenido[i] == '"' || Contenido[i] == '\'' || Contenido[i] == '`') {
            Comilla = Contenido[i]; Salida += Comilla;
            ++i;
            while ((i < Contenido.Length) && (Contenido[i] != Comilla)) {
                Salida += Contenido[i]; i++;
            }
            Salida += Comilla;
        }
        else {
            Salida += Contenido[i];
        }
    }

    try {
         File.WriteAllText(direccion, Salida);
    }
    catch { /* Arroja algun error :) */ }

    return Salida;
}
```

Lo que hace este último método es que ignora los valores que están entre comillas de tipo: `""`, `''` y `` ` `` con el objetivo de dejar los valores completamente en orden, lo he probado con el siguiente contenido en un csv:

```
yo,tu,el,"nosotros somos"
si,bien,"contenido",'nope'
```

Nota: El nuevo metodo utiliza 3 argumentos, el primero es la direccion del csv, el segundo es el delimitador y el tercero el nuevo delimitador.

---

Referencias:

- [`string.Replace(string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`File.ReadAllText(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`File.WriteAllText(string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)

Saludos :)

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Muy bien condimentada @NaCl!

Comment: @NaCl, excelente respuesta. Muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: @NaCl, perdona una duda, en la variable direccion, tienes que poner la ruta del archivo csv? y si es asi, al ejecutarla este va a remplazar el archivo existente?

Comment: @NaCl, gracias por tu ayuda. Lo que no entiendo es como hacerlo funcionar. Tengo una aplicacion consola la cual llama a esta funcion que tu me diste pasando 3 parametros (el primero es el archivo el cual necesito modificar, el segundo es el separador y el tercero es el nuevo separador que requiero) pero al ejecutarlo no hace nada. De que forma va a obtener el nuevo archivo con los cambios?

Comment: @Aarancibia No se que pasa que no lo haces funcionar, pero tal como está  la función a mi me funciona [_(Ver fiddle con modificaciones)_](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5BRBM6) con strings que tienen elementos separados por coma, el único error que vi es que no ponía los saltos de línea cuando pasaba por un valor entre comillas, ya lo arreglé.

Comment: Ya hice la misma prueba que tu, ya modifca las entradas pero tu uso en el string de la direccion tu uso el camino a el archivo directamente (archivo csv) pero el remplazo hacer que tome todas las comillas y las borre sin incluir el otro separador especificado

Comment: Un detalle que había olvidado mencionar es que el parametro pasado por `direccion` es el mismo documento, tanto de entrada como de salida.

Comment: @NaCl, si ya me resulto!! muchas gracias!! tengo que modifcar un archivo con mas de 160000 entradas (pesa 180 mb) asique se demorara un poco, pero de resto, excelente!!! te agradezco mucho la ayuda!

Comment: Otra alternativa a la volada: notepad, Control+H, poner el caracter para reemplazar y el nuevo valor. Reemplazar a todos y listo :D