# ¿Como seleccionar elementos dentro de un csv en C#?

Tags: c#

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un csv con dos lineas separadas al final por ; y cada palabra separada por , tal que así:

**prueba.csv**

```
gato,casa,http,antonio;
perro,abanico,https,libro;
```

ahora quiero seleccionar la primera fila  y meter en variables cada nombre por ejemplo *string* gato = gato que viene del **csv** solo de la primera fila y luego lo mismo con la segunda he probado con este código pero solo me esta pillando las letras :

c#

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int contador;
        string datos;


        var ruta = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        ruta = ruta + "/prueba.csv";


        var lineas = File.ReadAllText(ruta);

        Console.Write(lineas.Split(';'));


            Console.ReadKey();



    }
```

Comment: Tu enfoque es parcialmente erróneo, al hacer `Split(';')` estas cortando cada vez que veas un punto y coma, no una nueva linea, puede que tengas datos como este en tu conjunto: `gato,casa;comida,antonio,miguel;` lo que dará como resultado: `gato,casa` y `comida,antonio,miguel` y todo eso está en la misma línea, sin mencionar que al buscar un `;` al final de la linea  dejará el `\n` en el inicio de la nueva "linea" que separas con `Split()`.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como convertir el delimitador de un archivo csv](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/133166/4499)

Comment: como lo enfocarias entoces es mejor poner en el csv una , al final ??

Comment: No, en lugar de hacer `ReadAllText(ruta)` y luego `Split(';')`, haría [`ReadAllLines(ruta)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) e iteraría sobre el array de `string` retornado. Con eso puedes evitar que `;` sea un delimitador de linea y puede ser removido, te quedas con el `'\n'` como delimitador (o `'\r\n'` en Windows) y `ReadAllLines` se encarga de partir la entrada en lineas.

Comment: vale gracias y lo de meter los campos separados por coma en variables como seria ??

Comment: @ortiga, inserta estos valores en un arreglo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo estos valores de prueba:

```
gato,casa,http,antonio;
perro,abanico,https,libro;
```

He modificado el código para lograr lo que entiendo buscas obtener con tu programa:

Ejemplo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int contador;
   string datos;

   // Arreglo de strings que guardará las líneas que terminen en punto y coma (;).
   string[] arreglo_lineas = null;

   var ruta = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
   ruta = ruta + "/prueba.csv";
   arreglo_lineas = File.ReadAllText(ruta).Split(';');

   Console.log('Esta es la primera línea: ' + arreglo_lineas[0]);
   // Imprimiría: Esta es la primera línea: gato,casa,http,antonio;

   Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: luego quiero iterar sobre los campos de ese array como se haria eso???

Comment: @ortiga, te recomiendo publicar una nueva pregunta, pero allí debes colocar también qué has intentado para poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: gracias y la he publicado sabes como se limpian las variables en c#